# Translating AppleScript if-clause to its JavaScript equivalent

Tags: javascript, applescript, osascript

I don't know if the issue lies with me or with `OS X`.
I have this AppleScript:

```
tell application "Caffeine"
    if active then
        turn off
    else
        turn on
    end if
end tell
```

I translated this to this JavaScript

```
caffeine = Application("Caffeine");
if (caffeine.active)
{
    caffeine.turnOff();
}
else
{
    caffeine.turnOn();
}
```

However `caffeine.turnOn();` is never executed, no matter how often I run it. If Caffeine is active, it is turned off, otherwise nothing. The AppleScript equivalent runs. `caffeine.turnOn();` and `caffeine.turnOff();` by itself also run fine. I can't imagine, that JavaScript for OSA is really this broken, that even this doesn't work.

Comment: Might be `caffeine.active()`?

Comment: Okay wow, that's it. It said `active` was a property. I guess I have to brush up on my JS skills. However it's still weird, that it worked partially.

Answer (score 1):

`caffeine.active` might be a function, which when *not* called will always be truly:

```
var my_fn = function() {};
if (my_fn) console.log('my_fn is truly');
```

Call the function:

```
var caffeine = Application("Caffeine");
if (caffeine.active()) {
    caffeine.turnOff();
}
else {
    caffeine.turnOn();
}
```

A way to check it, is to simply log the value:

```
console.log(caffeine.active); // function() { .... }
// or using typeof
console.log(typeof caffeine.active); // "function"
```

Comment: When I say `console.log(caffeine.active)` it says `[object objectSpecifier]`, which displays the Obj-C underworkings of Apple's JS implementation.

Comment: @hgiesel What about `typeof caffeine.active`

Comment: Ok, this one says `function`. I guess even though Apple distinguishes between *properties* and *methods*, there seems to be no such differentiation for the JS implementation